# Remote connection doesn't work for MongoDB 3.2.9 (even after commenting out bindIp)

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to remotely connect to MongoDB 3.2.9 installed on a Windows 7 machine.
I have tried -

1. Setting bindIp to 0.0.0.0 in mongod.conf
2. Setting bindIp to specific IP addresses
3. Commenting out bindIp

(And of course, I have restarted MongoDB service after making any change to mongod.conf)

However, when I uninstalled MongoDB **3.2.9** and installed MongoDB **3.0.6** instead, I am able to connect to it remotely.
I would really appreciate any help or pointers regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 mongo 0.0.0.0:27017/test -u username -p password
```

instead of

```
mongo username:password@0.0.0.0:27017/test
```